# How to link ELF32 assembly and C files?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, nasm

I wrote a simple piece of Assembly software (nasm) and a simple application in C.
My C code calls a function from the Assembly code, but I don't know how to compile the C code without receiving a 'undefined reference' error from the 'extern int Sum();' line.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int Sum();

main()
{
  int a1, a2, x;

  x = Sum(a1, a2);
  printf("value of x is: %d\n", x);
}
```

Assembly code:

```
global _Sum

_Sum:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp

    mov  eax, [ebp+8]
    mov  ecx, [ebp+12]
    add  eax, ecx
    pop  ebp
    ret
```

How would i compile these two files separately and link them together into one unified file afterwards?

Comment: I know this question is old : However,to someone who comes here--The link to the code and the referenced book I have provided in my answer below is great resource to learn assembly.Hope you get a chance to check that out!

Answer (score 2):

You should assemble the .asm file to get a .o (object) file, as you said you've done.  Then you should compile (but not link) the .c file to get another .o file, like this:

```
gcc -o whatever.o -c whatever.c
```

Then you should link them together, like this:

```
gcc whatever.o asm.o
```

Then the linker will be run with all the object code at once, and should be able to resolve the references it needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that just gives me this error: main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Sum'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: ...when you run the first command or the second one?  Can you paste all the commands you are running until the first failure?

Comment: Also, can you dump the contents of your assembly-code object file using objdump or similar, so we can see what symbols it actually contains?

Comment: 1st: gcc -c main.c (result: main.o) 2nd: nasm -f elf func.asm (result: func.o) 3rd: gcc main.o func.o (result: main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Sum'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status)

Comment: objdump -t func.o:     file format elf32-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS* 00000000 func.asm
00000000 l    d  .text 00000000 .text
00000000 g       .text 00000000 _Sum

Comment: So what if you rename _Sum to Sum in your ASM, or Sum to _Sum in your C code?  I bet that will finish this off.

Answer (score 2):

In ABI used with ELF, C names aren't mangled with an initial `_`.

Comment: mangling is dictated by the compilers, and GCC mangles C function names with the leading underscore

Comment: @Foo, GCC does what the target ABI wants and I know of no ABI used with ELF which mangles C names with an initial `_`.  GCC will mangles when targeting other ABI if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to solve this, compile the C source as C (NOT C++), to compile it as C you must give it the extension .c

The second way, in C++ code (extension .cpp) names are mangled, when you compile the C++ code use a hex editor to look in the object file and search for Sum. In my case the name becomes `_Z3Sumii`. If you change the name in the assembler source to this, you'll find that it works.

Also change the `extern` statement in the C++ source to the following because it takes two parameters of type `int`, for example, `extern int Sum(int, int);`

```
  global _Z3Sumii
_Z3Sumii:
  push ebp
  mov  ebp, esp
  mov  eax, [ebp+8]
  mov  ecx, [ebp+12]
  add  eax, ecx
  mov  esp, ebp
  pop  ebp
  ret
```

To compile:

```
gcc -c file.cpp
nasm -f elf32 sum.asm -o sum.o
gcc file.o sum.o -o file
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who comes searching here:  Check out the code and book over here http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/index.php  :  Downloadthe linux examples over [here](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/linux-ex.zip) :  The file you would want to refer is  first.asm   - (Compile it according to architecture: 32 bits example below )

```
nasm -f elf -d ELF_TYPE asm_io.asm
nasm -f  elf32 first.asm 
gcc -o first first.o driver.c asm_io.o
```

Answer (score 0):

The most native way is to use GCC toolchain to obtain assembler code of your C program, then manually assembly both assembler files and link them.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to link the code together without the use of GCC generated assembly?

Comment: What you are talking about is two different stages of compilation process - asembling and linking. To link files manually, you can use standart 'ld' utility.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that when I assemble the .asm file. No problem. I get an .o file. When I compile the .c file with GCC, it gives me an error about an undefined reference to 'Sub', but I'm not able to link the files and thereby clearing the error before the .c file is compiled. That's my dilemma.

Comment: Since the 'Sub' is marked external, all you need to do is to restrict linker in GCC toolchain and link the files manually. Also, there shold be an option in GCC to link external files to the code.

Comment: As far as restricting the linker, I compile with this command: gcc -c main.c and then it compiles fine, and then I assemble the Assembly code with this command: nasm -f elf func.asm, and finally I link like this: ld main.o func.o -o program, but that gives me this error: ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048080
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Sum'
main.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `printf'

Comment: First link in my Searcher? http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html

Answer (score 0):

In your circumstance:

```
nasm -f elf -o sumasm.o sumasm.asm
gcc -o sum sumasm.o sum.c
```

you may need `elf32`